# Are questions about BeOS on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Part of BeOS conforms to POSIX (probably an older edition). Would any question on certain aspect of BeOS be on-topic here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the same rules we apply for [macOS and Android](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) could apply to BeOS:

> - The Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)
> - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)

The conforming parts would be on-topic, the more exotic parts wouldn't be.

(It might be completely on topic on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), but a quick search didn't show (m)any questions about BeOS specifically.)